# Nautilus crash "aborted ('core' dumped)"

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, freeze

I have Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 and I have a problem with nautilus. When I opened, it then closes itself instantly, making also the desktop icons disappear. Usually it closes when I open a new folder.

Also it freezes sometimes and I can only close it with `xkill`, so I tried to investigate the problem in terminal and get this error message:

```
ERROR:nautilus-directory.c:631:nautilus_directory_remove_file: assertion failed: (node != NULL)

Aborted (`core' dumped)
```

Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Does anyone know what the error is trying to tell us (631 error)

Comment: `nautilus-directory.c:631` means that error was raised at the line# `631` of the source file `nautilus-directory.c`

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Comment: I already tried that. Also I tried removing all nautilus extensions (like dropbox or python),

Comment: How about the `nautilus-sound-converter` extension? try removing that too. It's a cause too.

Comment: I don't have that one installed (not even on my repos)

Comment: Does it work as root user?

Comment: No, the same error is shown up

Comment: This is my last suggestion (and it may be a bad idea): login into tty1 (CTRL+ALT+F1) and run `sudo apt-get purge nautilus` then `sudo apt-get install nautilus`

Comment: I tried that also. Also beside that i made all kind of removes (config removes, purge, etc). The only thing i could find (I i'm not sure is that's what is causing the problem) is that it has something to do with the glibc libraries.